# How to append to an existing file with WSO2 ESB (VFS)

Tags: append, wso2, vfs, wso2-esb

I'm writing to a single file with a WSO2 ESB using a VFS endpoint. But this does override the file each time. **How can I configure the endpoint to append the content?** Or does this feature even exist?

```
<inSequence>
    <log level="full"/>type="STRING"/>
    <property name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName" expression="myOutputFile.txt" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
    <send>
        <endpoint>
            <address uri="vfs:file://C:/MyOutputDirectory"/>
        </endpoint>
    </send>
</inSequence>
```

*(my content is text/plain)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to append to the same file, define the transport.vfs.Append=true parameter with the file address URI[1]

```
<address uri="vfs:file://C:/MyOutputDirectory?transport.vfs.Append=true"/>
```

[1]http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB450/VFS+Transport

Comment: Ok this works. But do you know why setting a property not work? `<property name="transport.vfs.Append" value="true" scope="transport"/>`

Comment: That is not the way to do it. The property transport.vfs.Append must be set as a query parameter to file uri. The Docs have been updated accordingly as I pointed in the answer.